# When should the save method be called in Django?

Tags: python, django

Should the save method be called after every `create` method or does calling the `create` method automatically call the `save` method?

If the `save` method is called automatically after creating an object then what would be a good use-case for the `save` method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No `save()` does not need to be called after `create()`.

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) for create:

> A convenience method for creating an object and saving it all in one step

its to be used in place of creating an object the normal way then saving with object.save()

Answer (score 4):

The `save` method should be used when you modify an object that you got by any other means than `create`, such as `.objects.get`. Otherwise, your modifications are lost.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample snippet that shows a good use for the save method. This is basically taking data from a submitted form and then adding additional info "behind the scenes".

```
#Model
class Foo(models.Model):
    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field_two = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field_three = models.CharField(max_length=10)

#Form
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        exclude = ('field_three')  #form will just show field_one and field_two

#View
def FooView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        form = FooForm(request.POST)  #gets field_one and two from form data
        if form.is_valid():
            new_foo = form.save(commit = False) #doesn't actually save yet
            new_foo.field_three = 'Foobar!' #add data to field_three
            new_foo.save() #now it saves all 3 fields
    else:
        form = FooForm()
    return #add some sort of http response here
```

Here's the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) with some more info on save() and commit=False

As an aside- I just realized that if you are adding a static string to a model like my example shows, you're doing it wrong. But idea is there haha.